# How to display a loading icon on every request in the api

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2, android-jetpack-compose

How to display a loading icon on every request in the API? On the first request it shows the progress icon but on the second request it's like it cached and didn't show the load.

My viewModel:

```
class CadastroViewModel:ViewModel() {
    private val cadastroRepository= CadastroRepository()

    private val _resultado: MutableStateFlow<MessageCad> = MutableStateFlow(MessageCad())
    val resultado: StateFlow<MessageCad>
        get() = _resultado


    fun create(nome: String,email: String,cpf:String,telefone:String,
               celular:String,senha:String,endereco:String,bairro:String,numero:String,
               complemento:String,cidade:String
    ){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

               val r = cadastroRepository.createUser(nome,email,cpf,telefone,celular,senha,endereco,bairro,
                        numero,complemento,cidade)
                _resultado.value = r

            } catch (e:Exception) {
                Log.d("Service error",e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My view model call :

```
val value: MessageCad by model.resultado.collectAsState(initial = MessageCad())
    
if(value.message.isEmpty()){
    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like `value.message.isEmpty()` never returning true after first call because `model.resultado` always have a result that is not empty.

You should either create a loading flag

```
private val _loading = MutableStateFlow(Boolean)
val loading: StateFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _loading
```

set it as

```
  viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
               _loading.value = true
               val r =  cadastroRepository.createUser(nome,email,cpf,telefone,celular,senha,endereco,bairro,
                        numero,complemento,cidade)
                _resultado.value = r

            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.d("Service error",e.toString())
            }finally {
              _loading.value = false
            }

        }
```

or use `ViewState` approach to have `Loading`, Success or Error states to display for any possible state of your api call.

Comment: Thank you very much. I make both calls now: `val loading: Boolean by model.loading.collectAsState()
            val value: MessageCad by model.result.collectAsState(initial = MessageCad())`